# Apple Transport Security

Tags: swift, ssl

I have written some swift code to display images from psychicliving.co.uk

Unfortunately the images do not appear but I can see images hosted from different servers.

I have done some reading around apples security policies and suspect that the issue may be to do with the servers SSL certificate. When I set the AllowAritaryLoads to YES the images load properly.

When I run a check on the sites SSL certificate I can see that TLS 1.2 protocol is not enabled.

Would this be the reason the images are not loading? or am I missing something?

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.psychicliving.co.uk/images/Michael.jpg")
if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as! URL) {
    cell.imgCarNane.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your images aren't loading without the arbitrary load is because you don't use TLS 1.2 indeed :

> your communication through higher-level APIs needs to be encrypted
>   using TLS version 1.2 with forward secrecy.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-DontLinkElementID_12